# Laravel parent variable ng-click

Tags: angularjs, laravel, angularjs-scope, parent-child, angularjs-ng-click

I am having troubles with Angular in Laravel. I am trying to change a variable by clicking on a button.

**For this I wrote the following code:**

```
<div class="user-team-navigation col-sm-12" id="user-team-navigation" >
        <ul>
            <div ng-repeat="user_team in user_teams" ng-if="user_team.user_id == {{ $user_id }}">
                <li><button ng-click="$parent.current_user_team = user_team.id">@{{ user_team.name }} @{{ $parent.current_user_team }}</button></li>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**My controller looks like this:**

```
angular.module('wtmApp').controller('rideruserteamList', function($scope, $http) {

$scope.order_by = 'id';
$scope.order_way = 'asc';

$http.get('/API/userteamriders-list.php').then(
    function(response) {
        $scope.rider_userteams = response.data.rider_userteams;
    }
);

$scope.current_user_team = 1;
$scope.amount_of_riders = 0;
```

});

**Later in the code I am calling upon the variable: $parent.current_user_team**
But it wil not update. It should switch to team 2 of the user, but it remains showing the riders from team 1. by writing the following code:

```
<div class="riders col-sm-3" ng-repeat="rider_userteam in rider_userteams" ng-if="rider_userteam.user_id == {{ $user_id }} && rider_userteam.user_team_id == $parent.current_user_team">
```

**As you could see earlier I am printing the variable on the ng-click button as well**
The variable that is shown does change, but only on the particular button. So the variable does not get changed outside the scope of ng-click. Do you have any suggestion **how I can make my $parent.current_user_team variable outside the ng-click**.

I look forward to your replies! Let me know if additional information is necessary.

Rutger

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using $parent/$root/normal variable, simply use object. Please find the code snippet.

```
<div class="user-team-navigation col-sm-12" id="user-team-navigation" >
      <ul>
            <div ng-repeat="user_team in user_teams" ng-if="user_team.user_id == {{ $user_id }}">
                <li><button ng-click="current_user_team.id = user_team.id">@{{ user_team.name }} @{{ $parent.current_user_team }}</button></li>
            </div>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Same variable change in controller,

```
angular.module('wtmApp').controller('rideruserteamList', function($scope, $http){

$scope.order_by = 'id';
$scope.order_way = 'asc';

$http.get('/API/userteamriders-list.php').then(
    function(response) {
        $scope.rider_userteams = response.data.rider_userteams;
    }
);

$scope.current_user_team = {
   id:1
};
$scope.amount_of_riders = 0; 
});
```

html,

```
<div class="riders col-sm-3" ng-repeat="rider_userteam in rider_userteams" ng-if="rider_userteam.user_id == {{ $user_id }} && rider_userteam.user_team_id == current_user_team.id">
```

Please refer the [scope hierarchy](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) in angularjs docs